What is this question on embeddings asking me to prove (I don't anyone to actually solve the question for me)?
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. To learn the material, I make sure that I complete every problem on my own before asking for help or a check. However, I'm a bit confused on the wording of this problem:

Show that any two smooth embeddings $f, g : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ are homotopic through smooth embeddings.

Is this a correct re-wording of the problem?

Show that  for any two smooth embeddings $f , g : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$, there is a continuous family of maps $h_t : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ where $h_0 = f$, $h_1 = g$, and $h_t$ is an embedding for all $0 \le t \le 1$.

In other words, I need to show a homotopy between both maps, and also that each intermediate $h_t$ is itself a smooth embedding. Would this be the correct interpretation of what I need to prove?

Yes, that's right. Essentially the question is to show that there aren't any nontrivial (smooth) knots in $\mathbb{R}^4$.
